# bubblesort from highest to lowest number in java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm looking for a bubblesort code in java that is opposite of the usual thing that I'm seeing when I search the internet. 
I don't really understand the code below, all I know is that it sorts a bunch of numbers from lowest to highest. Is the code below modifiable so that instead of outputting the numbers from lowest to highest. It outputs it as highest to lowest?

```
int i;
    int array[] = {12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10};
    System.out.println("Values Before the sort:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      System.out.print( array[i]+"  ");
    System.out.println();
    bubble_srt(array, array.length);
    System.out.print("Values after the sort:\n");
    for(i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
      System.out.print(array[i]+"  ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("PAUSE");
  }

  public static void bubble_srt( int a[], int n ){
    int i, j,t=0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(j = 1; j < (n-i); j++){
        if(a[j-1] > a[j]){
          t = a[j-1];
          a[j-1]=a[j];
          a[j]=t;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
if(a[j-1] > a[j]){
```

to

```
if(a[j-1] < a[j]){
```

Comment: wouldn't that be a '<=' instead of '<'?

Comment: you wouldnt need to switch if the value is =

Answer (score 3):

Some words about your code:

If you move the swap-method out of your inner loop, it get's more readable, and more easy to reason about the independent parts.

```
public void swap (int i, int j, int [] arr) {
    int tmp = arr [i];
    arr [i] = arr [j];
    arr [j] = tmp;
}
```

Sweet little methods are easy to understand and test, which is important.

Don't declare the index variables outside the for. This makes it harder to reason about your code - the variables are visible without necessity outside the loop. In the old code, you gain nothing from declaring tmp outside of the inner loop. Declaration is cost-free at runtime.

```
public static void bubbleSort (int a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n-i); j++) {
            if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
                swap (j, j-1, a);
            }
        }
    }
}

    // ... missing ...
```

Don't repeat yourself. Move duplicated code into a method.

```
public static void show (int [] arr)
{
    for (int i : arr) 
        System.out.print (i + " ");
    System.out.println ();
}
```

Sweet little methods are easy to test. Use the simplified for-loop, whenever possible, to avoid off-by-one-errors, and to be more robust to code changes - they work for Lists too, for example.

```
    int array[] = {12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10};
    System.out.println ("Values Before the sort:\n");
    show (array);
    bubbleSort (array, array.length);
    System.out.print ("Values after the sort:\n");
    show (array);
    System.out.println ("PAUSE");
}
```

With the simplified code, it get's more easy to reason about, what which part does.

```
if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
```

needs just to be changed

```
if (a[j-1] < a[j]) {
```

to reverse the order.

Answer (score 2):

you could change the bubblesort to satisfy your needs or leave it as is and walk the sorted array backwards. for both, you should try to understand such a little piece of code instead of simply asking for the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

`for(i = array.length -1; i >=0; i--)

{

  System.out.println(array[i]);

}`

Should work.  You start at the end of the array and go backwards

Comment: shouldn't that be for(i = array.length - 1; i >=0; i--)?